# Events not triggered when button is added via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using AJAX to dynamically add a button to the DOM. This button is supposed to trigger a function on click but it's not.

Here is the MWE:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- The btn is added here -->  
    <div id="btn_content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**btn.html**

```
<button class="my_btn">Click here</button>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Adds the button to index.html
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "btn.html",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (html_text) {
            $('#btn_content').html(html_text);
        }
    });

    // Click event that is not triggerd
    $('.my_btn').click(function () { 
        console.log("This is not working");
    })
});
```

A similar issue was mentionned but not answered with a practical solution at the time.
[Submit button does not trigger on items added via ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557905/submit-button-does-not-trigger-on-items-added-via-ajax)

Any thoughts?

Comment: When the event listener is registered, the buttons do not exist. Try listening to ```$(document).on("click", ".my_btn", ...```

Comment: You need add your event handler to the element *after* it is added to the DOM. Alternatively, and more simply, use a delegated event handler: `$('#btn_content').on('click', '.my_btn', function () {... `